# How to extract a string from an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, minecraft

So I am making a plugin for a Minecraft server and I had to get my command command argument from one class to another and After trying multiple things, I started using an ArrayList, It worked for the most part but it put brackets around
the argument.

```java
ArrayList<String> target = Main.target;
      
@EventHandler
public void invClickEvent(InventoryClickEvent e) {
  
  Inventory inv = e.getInventory();
  Player player = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
  
  String name = inv.getName();
  if ( name.equals(ChatColor.RED + "Ban Menu")) {
  
    e.setCancelled(true);
    int slot = e.getSlot();
    if (slot < 0) return;
    if (slot == 0) {
      player.performCommand("kill " + target);
      player.closeInventory();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

That is the code that is giving me troubles.  It is pulling the data from my main class.  It the ArrayList is pulling text from an argument.

```java
public static ArrayList<String> target = new ArrayList<String>();
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

if (sender instanceof Player && args.length == 1) {
  Player p = (Player) sender;
  if (args.length > 0) {
    switch (args.length) {
      case 1: 
        Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
        if (player == null) {
          sender.sendMessage("That player is not online");
          
        } else if (player.isOnline()) {
      
          Menus.openMenu(p);
          target.add(player.getPlayerListName());
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That is where the array is pulling the argument. The output would be something like `player executed command: /kill [HoloPanio]` and I want it to output `player executed command: /kill HoloPanio`

If there is another method to import the arguments please let me know, if not then please tell me how to fix this issue.

Thanks!

## **Clarification**

To clarify on what I originally meant with this question was that I was trying to store a string inside of an ArrayList in Java, and when I went to retrieve the value I was expecting nothing but a plain string.

I was in fact using the incorrect type for the variable that I was assigning the string to.  I should've been using type `String` as pointed out by several people.  so the correct way of doing this would look like:

```java
public String target;
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

  if (sender instanceof Player && args.length == 1) {
      Player p = (Player) sender;
      if (args.length > 0) {
          switch (args.length) {
          case 1: 
            Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
            if (player == null) {
              sender.sendMessage("That player is not online");
              
            } else if (player.isOnline()) {
          
              Menus.openMenu(p);
              target = player.getPlayerListName();
              
            }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

In the above code block I am declaring the `target` variable as a string then setting it further down with the line `target = player.getPlayerListName();`.  This is a much more efficient way defining the value. The only change that would need to be made to the first block is changing:

```java
ArrayList<String> target = Main.target;
```

to

```java
String target = Main.target;
```

### **Final Note**

This post was originally written when I was still learning java and would like to add that I would not use an ArrayList for a string nor would I define it statically as I had done when this post was originally written.

Comment: That is because that is how the result of `ArrayList.toString()` looks like. If you're only trying to keep a reference to only one `String`, do that using a `String` variable instead of an `ArrayList`

Comment: Could you me more specific?

Comment: Instead of `public static ArrayList<String> target = new ArrayList<String>();` use `public static String target;` and instead of `target.add(player.getPlayerListName());` use `target = player.getPlayerListName();`. This will make it work but is not an optimal solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding on what Titus has said in their comment.

Instead of using `ArrayList`, try using a `String` as the type for target. This will allow the output to be `player executed command: /kill HoloPanio`.

```
String target = Main.target;

@EventHandler
public void invClickEvent(InventoryClickEvent e) {

   Inventory inv = e.getInventory();
   Player player = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();

   String name = inv.getName();
   if ( name.equals(ChatColor.RED + "Ban Menu")) {

       e.setCancelled(true);
       int slot = e.getSlot();
       if (slot < 0)
       {
           return;
       }
       if (slot == 0)
       {
           player.performCommand("kill " + target);
           player.closeInventory();
           return;
       }
```

The below would be updated to initial target as an empty `String`. Note that a static variable will be updated for every user of this class. This means that any other code accessing this class will have the same target. And, any other code accessing this class can change the target.

```
public static String target = "";

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {



    if (sender instanceof Player && args.length == 1)
    {
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            switch (args.length)
            {
            case 1: 
              Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
              if (player == null) {
                sender.sendMessage("That player is not online");

              } else if (player.isOnline()) {

                  Menus.openMenu(p);
                  target = player.getPlayerListName();

              }
```

Also as Titus said, this is not the best solution because, as a static variable, the `target` will likely change when you don't want it to (or will end up being the same when you want it to change). But, this should solve the command issue.

Comment: When I do this, It looks like it does not event set the varible

Answer (score 0):

This is default ArrayList toString.

Use to String.join to remove the brackets

```
String result = String.join("", list);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because of toString method of ArrayList class.

Extends the ArryList class and override the toString

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString().substring(1,super.toString().length-1) ;
    }
};
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Extending a class *just* to get this functionality is incredibly hacky and difficult to maintain.  There are few developers who would immediately reach for inheritance as a way to solve a problem like this.  There are better ways to print collections.  Inheritance is not one of them.

Answer (score -1):

Speaking absolutely nothing to the Minecraft angle, if you wanted to get the list of elements back and not have to print the collection, you could aggregate it with a `StringJoiner` instead.

```
String values = String.join(",", target);
System.out.println(values);
```